# Dynamic SQL to iterate over all columns based on a complex Static SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a static SQL query which finds out blank counts and data types (whether numeric or alphanumeric etc). Below is the query:

```
SELECT
case when Pattern = '' then 'BLANK' else Pattern end AS Pattern,
LEN(case when Pattern = '' then 'BLANK' else Pattern end) Length,
COUNT(*) AS Count FROM
     ( SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(      
     REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( 
     REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( 
     REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE    
     (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(col_name),'A','A'),'B','A') ,'C','A') ,'D','A') 
     ,'E','A'),'F','A') ,'G','A') ,'H','A') ,'I','A'),'J','A') ,'K','A') ,'L','A') ,'M','A')     
     ,'N','A') ,'O','A') ,'P','A')
     ,'Q','A'),'R','A') ,'S','A') ,'T','A') ,'U','A') ,'V','A') ,'W','A') ,'X','A') ,'Y','A')    
     ,'Z','A'),'8','N'),'7','N'),'6','N'),'5','N'),'4','N'),'3','N')   
     ,'2','N'),'1','N'),'0','N'),'9','N')  
 AS Pattern FROM table_name) A  GROUP BY Pattern;
```

Now, lets say I have a below table

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
 Column1 varchar(50),
 Column2 varchar(50),
 Column3 varchar(50),
 Column4 varchar(50),
   )
INSERT INTO Data
 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4)
VALUES 
 (NULL, NULL, 'ABC123', 'abc '),
 ('xyz', NULL, 'MNO300', 'XYZ123 ')
```

Now I want a output like below:

```
Count_Pat_1 --> Count is of only one data type i.e. either Alphabetic or 
Numeric
Count_Part_2 --> Count is of mixed data type i.e. contains both alphabet and 
number
Blank --> Count of NULL values

Col_name    Count_Pat_1    Count_Pat_2  Blank
Column1          1               0       1        
Column2          0               0       2
Column3          0               2       0
Column4          1               1       0
```

How can I generate the above table? Clearly I need to resort to Dynamic SQL where the entire sql string needs to be set as variable. Below is my approach:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = N''

SELECT @sql = @sql + CASE WHEN @stm = N'' THEN N'' ELSE N',' END +
  '('+
  '''' + c.name + ''', '+
  'CASE '+
   'WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ' +
   'ELSE 0 ' +
  'END, ' +
  'CASE '+
   'WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' IS NOT NULL THEN LEN(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') - ** the above SQL 
   script ***
  FROM sys.columns c
  JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
  WHERE t.name = 'Data'
```

But inserting the above SQL script at the place as indicated by ** will not be giving the output properly.

Hence any hints would be appreciated. SQL Server version: 2016

Comment: simply re-posting your closed question will not help get it answered. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps some sort of pattern would suffice PATINDEX()

Comment: Mitch: I guess I am quite clear on what I want to achieve. I need assistance or hints in completing the dynamic SQL that has been provided in my answer.

Comment: " I guess I am quite clear" - no, I'm afraid you are not.

Comment: @Mitch: `"How can I generate the above table?" `<--  This is the question I have asked. And as an approach I have given my code snippets.  Is this what you are looking for?